# Verificar se a Notification esta ativa

Tags: android, android-notification

Preciso identificar se uma *Notification* especifica (ID Notification) esta ainda ativa na lista de notificações do Android.

Situação: Tenho um método que cancela a *Notification* até aqui tudo funcionando corretamente, porém preciso que ao cancelar a notificação cancele um processo CountDownTimer (Neste ponto esta tudo funcionando corretamente).

Quem poder me ajudar agradeço.

Att.

Comment: Você quer cancelar apenas se ela estiver na lista?  Você pode cancelar uma notificação mesmo que ela não esteja na lista.

Comment: Olá Ramaral não preciso saber se ela se encontra na lista.

Comment: Então qual é o seu problema?

Comment: Desculpa escrevi coisa errada, eu preciso saber se ela se encontra na lista, mas meu problema não é para cancelar, pois isso eu já estou fazendo o que eu preciso é verificar se ela existe.

Comment: Como essa notificação é lançada, é através de um AlarmManager?

Comment: Estou usando NotificationManager e Notification.Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que eu tenha conhecimento isso só é possível a partir da *API18* através da implementação de um [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications%28%29) ou a partir da *API23* recorrendo ao método [getActiveNotifications()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#getActiveNotifications%28%29) do NotificationManager.

Implementar um [NotificationListenerService](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#getActiveNotifications%28%29) é algo custoso de mais só para saber se uma notificação está na lista.

Saber quando ela é apresentada é fácil, já que é você que a lança.
Para saber se ela foi cancelada use o método [setDeleteIntent()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) para indicar um *PendingIntent* que será lançado quando o usuário a cancelar.

Se ela foi lançada e o utilizador não a cancelou então ela está na lista.